# How to set alpha of uiclearcolor?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I am currently doing this:

```
UIColor *myColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

This is great but i would like to specify a certain alpha of "myColor". How would i do so?

Comment: `+ [UIColor clearColor]` actually returns a black with 100% transparency (or 0% opacity or an alpha value of 0.0). If you now want black with specific alpha, use `+ [UIColor blackColor]` for 1.0 alpha or `- [UIColor colorWithWhite:alpha:]`

Answer (score 127):

If you have an existing color, you can return a new one with a specified alpha, like this:

```
- (void)setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)color 
{
    self.backgroundColor = [color colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3f];
}
```

Comment: +1This is useful if you already have a color and wanted to set the opacity which is not possible with other APIS..

Answer (score 12):

`[UIColor clearColor]` is, how should I put it?, clear!

It is a convenience class method returning a `UIColor` with alpha at zero.

If you want a color with a fractional amount of transparency:

```
+ (UIColor *)colorWithRed:(CGFloat)red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue alpha:(CGFloat)alpha
```

Or one of the other `UIColor` class methods.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `colorWithWhite:alpha` like so:

```
[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.5];
```

Or if you want a specific color:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:0.3 alpha:0.72];
```

Check out [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 7):

For Swift you can use:

```
UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
```

Or RGB Colors:

```
UIColor(red: 0/255.0 , green: 0/255.0 , blue: 0/255.0 , alpha: 0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer that Question

```
UIColor *myColor = [[UIColor clearColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3f];
```

I assume that you have "clearColor" as a valid UIColor;

@refer James O'Brien Solution;

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a **simple** and yet **powerful** solution in Swift then checkout **[HandyUIKit](https://github.com/Flinesoft/HandyUIKit)**. Install it in your project *using Carthage* – then your life becomes easier:

```
import HandyUIKit

// creates a new UIColor object with the given value set
myColor.change(.alpha, to: 0.2)
```

There is also an option to apply a **relative change**:

```
// create a new UIColor object with alpha increased by 0.2
myColor.change(.alpha, by: 0.2)
```

I hope it helps!